# Eiffel: Unknown identifier on attached check into require statement

Tags: design-by-contract, eiffel, void-safety

```
    require
        valid_item: attached item as l_i and then l_i.valid_for_insert or l_i.valid_for_update
```

why do I have an unknown identifier here with l_i??!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
valid_item: attached item as l_i and then (l_i.valid_for_insert or l_i.valid_for_update)
```

Note you can also do

```
item_set: attached item as l_i 
valid_item: l_i.valid_for_insert or l_i.valid_for_update
```

you can reuse the object test local variable `l_i` from a previous precondition.

Comment: Very nice answer! could you explain me why? what is the priority of evaluation without parenthesis?

Comment: `a and then b or c `  is  `(a and then b) or c`
- `and`, `and then` behave the same.
`and then` is used when you want to be sure the "right" operand is evaluated only if the "left" one is True.
It is also used for Void-safety, as usually the right operand must be applied on non Void object.